# sql join tables based on 2 parameters and update 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

When I want to join 2 tables based on 1 parameter and update only 1 column, I use following syntax

```
UPDATE your_table
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.name= your_table.name
SET your_table.surname= your_temp_table.surname;
```

But what if I want to join tables based on 2 parameters (name and city) and update 2 columns (surname and date). Could you please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comma to set multiple columns:

```
UPDATE your_table
INNER JOIN your_temp_table on your_temp_table.name= your_table.name and 
            your_temp_table.city= your_table.city
SET your_table.surname= your_temp_table.surname,
    your_table.`date`=your_temp_table.`date`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alias for tables and join statement, after `from`.

```
update yt 
set yt.name='name_value', yt.date= 'date_value' 
from your_table yt
inner join your_temp_table ytt on ytt.surname= yt.surname 
and ytt.City = yt.City
```